# How to create a tool/GUI Builder like this in C# java or any language

Tags: c#, java, user-interface, opengl

I want to create a Tool which is something similar to this

[image: Screenshot]

I don't want to create with this many options, but just a basic set of 2/3 options like drawing lines. How do they build this kind of things? Can I build something similar in C# or Java? Also what I want to do is when ever someone draws something I will generate code in the background which will not be related to the drawing the person has created.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question can't really be answered in its current form. Could you narrow the focus of the question?

Comment: ok here is what I want to do I created a simple lines in openGL which is say for example 3 lines making a incomplete square. What i want to do is create a GUI application where user will instead of defining point on x axis and y axis in code manually gets an ability to draw. my application will generate code for them which they can use for what ever purpose they want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside previous example, you can go take a look at code from [SweetHome3D](http://www.sweethome3d.com). As its source is available, you can with ease inspire yourself from it.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with any language. If you choose Java, take a look  [here](http://www.mxgraph.com/) to see an example of what you can do with [jgraph](http://jgraph.com/).  mxGraphx is the freeware version of JGraph and comes with the mxGraphEditor, which is an example in source code of an application, very similar to the one you want to write.

Comment: thanks but it is a commercial product it is what i am looking for but any non commercial product will help

Comment: JGraph (Java) is the free version, mxGraph is the commercial product, to clarify.

Comment: @David: You are absolutely right. Thanx! Here are the link to the licenses: http://www.jgraph.com/license.html and http://www.jgraph.com/license.html and prices for mxGraph: http://www.jgraph.com/purchase.html

Answer (score 0):

As example you can download source of Inkspace vector editor http://inkscape.org/download/?lang=en